# How can I process this array more efficiently

Tags: swift

I have an array of names that looks like the following.
["John Doe", "Mary Blog"]

What I want to do is process this array and return an array with the initials like the following.

["JD", "MB"]

I have already done this but my code is ugly and inefficient (nested loops).
It's probably fine for a small array like in my example.

How can I process my array more efficiently?

```
       let contacts = ["John Doe", "Mary Blog"]
       var initalsArray: [String] = []
       let names = contacts.map {$0}

            for name in names {
                var initals: String = ""
                let fullname = name.components(separatedBy: " ")
                for part in fullname {
                    if part.count > 0 {
                        initals += part[0]
                    }
                }
                initalsArray.append(initals)
            }
```

Comment: Not necessarily more efficient, but can achieve the same result with *less code:* `let initialsArray = names.map { String($0.split(separator: " ").compactMap { $0.first }) }`

Comment: @MartinR I'll accept that as an answer on the grounds that it's less 'ugly' as per my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not compare the efficiency of this with the above answers but if you are  dealing with `names`, using `PersonNameComponentsFormatter` will help you a lot. Check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/personnamecomponentsformatter).

In your case following code gives the required output.

```
let formatter = PersonNameComponentsFormatter()

let contacts = ["John Doe", "Mary Blog"]
var initalsArray: [String] = []

for contact in contacts {
    if let name = formatter.personNameComponents(from: contact) {
        formatter.style = .abbreviated
        initalsArray.append(formatter.string(from: name))
    }
}
```

`output -> ["JD", "MB"]`

Comment: Cool, never heard of PersonNameComponentsFormatter before

Answer (score 3):

You *must* process all elements in the array.

For every element, you *must* detect the spaces and retrieve the next letter.

Then you *must* build up the output array with concatenated capitals.

So I really don't see how you could avoid a double loop.

Only `if part.count > 0` is unnecessary.

---

Alternatively, you can scan the strings yourself to avoid generating the intermediate array `fullname`.

You can probably also obtain the result by regex processing, but this would be a sledgehammer to crack nuts. Don't.

---

A possible implementation of the inner loop. (Sorry if this is invalid, I don't know Swift).

```
var space: Bool = true
for c in name {
  if space && c != ' ' {
    initials+= c
  } 
  space= c == ' '
}
```

Notice that the (optional) extra condition `c != ' '` protects against double spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use map to remove some of your own looping

```
let contacts = ["John Doe", "Mary Blog"]
let result = contacts.map { $0.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).map { String($0.prefix(1)) }.joined(separator: "") }
print(result)
```

I don't known if this is any quicker, maybe it gives Apple a chance to fro some optimisation that is hard to do

Answer (score 0):

Actually this answer though similar may be a bit quicker

```
let contacts = ["John Doe", "Mary Blog"]
let result = contacts.map { $0.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).reduce("") { $0 + String($1.prefix(1)) } }
print(result)
```

Instated of constructing inner arrays and then joining them I just added it to the string of previous first letters

Comment: Please do not post multiple answers, edit your original answer instead with this alternative